# MVC .NET 3 ModelState and ValidationResults

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, modelstate

I have problem. I use [IBAN] Atrribute with nHibernate ORM. Everything work fine except one thing. When I input wrong IBAN I get information about it in object.ValidationResults() but I don't have it in ModelState so I dont get error information in ValidationSummary. Why there is difference between ValidationResust() and ModelState.

I checked it 100 times, I'm sure that I dont remove this value from ModelState. What could be reason. I can't give you my code cause it's too big project, so please give me possible reasons.

Thanks

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

could be due to model binder not kicking in properly.. Please try calling `TryValidateModel();` manually in your controller. Something similar is discussed at http://johan.driessen.se/posts/testing-dataannotation-based-validation-in-asp.net-mvc